# How can i make a content be fixed when the margin of the content next to it is moving?

Tags: html, css, css-position, margins

So I'm doing my first project in HTML and CSS, and one of the tasks is to align 4 icons side by side (horizontally) and make them "grow" a little bit when I pass the mouse over it. The problem is, when a pass the mouse, the border grows - and to maintain the margin it pushes the other icons around, and I don't want to do that, I want only the one icon my cursor is over to move. I've been looking for a solution for 3 hours now and I can't find it.
Hope this got clear. Here's my code in HTML and CSS:

```css
.icones {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  border: solid #ffffff;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 70px;
}

.icons a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: solid red;
}

.icons a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.02);
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icones">
  <div class="icons">
    <a href="http://" target="_blank">
      <ion-icon name="logo-github"></ion-icon>
    </a>
    <a href="http://" target="_blank">
      <ion-icon name="logo-whatsapp"></ion-icon>
    </a>
    <a href="http://" target="_blank">
      <ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon>
    </a>
    <a href="http://" target="_blank">
      <ion-icon name="logo-discord"></ion-icon>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see your CSS hover animation. Are you using an external library icon or are you missing some CSS code? IF it's the latter, please add it so I can help.

Comment: oww ok, I forget to add on the question, I will eddit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `scale` on `:hover` (and `transition` for a nice animation).
Also, don't change `padding` or `margin` (btw, use `gap` instead) on hover.

```css
.icons a {
  /* Default styles here ... */
  transition: scale 0.3s;
}

.icons a:hover {
  /* Hover styles here ... */
  scale: 1.5;
}
```

Example:

```css
.icons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  gap: 1rem; /* instead of margin */
}

.icons a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: solid red;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  transition: scale 0.3s, border-radius 0.3s;
}

.icons a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.02);
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  scale: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <a href="http://" target="_blank"></a>
  <a href="http://" target="_blank"></a>
  <a href="http://" target="_blank"></a>
  <a href="http://" target="_blank">❤️</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work. The position of the other icons keep changing

Comment: @GuilhermeSilva added a demo.

Comment: what is a demo?

Comment: @GuilhermeSilva refresh the page. I've edited my answer with a **demo**nstration snippet.

Comment: ow I saw it, it worked thanks. I not sure why tough lol, but i'will figure it out

Comment: why gap intead of margin?

Comment: @GuilhermeSilva You can use `margin` on the children. I used `gap` on the parent just to show you what else can be used when using `flex`. And there are some slight differences in that `gap` is in-between the items. Margin is all around every item. So as you desire. Use what best fits your task needs.

Comment: uhmm got it. or almost lmao. I used margin on the children now and it still working. And it is very smooth. thank you

Comment: Only one more question. Why when a made the question, the CSS code was not with "colors", like in the code format? What I needed to do? Asking for future questions.

Comment: When you click the question's [Edit] button you'll see the markup editor. There's also the `{}` button that will insert at the caret position a code snippet. Please read: [How to create a runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) That's regarding a runnable snippet. If you only want to *"colorize"* a code use three backticks followed by the language like  ```js in the same line. Read more how to style the markdown markup by clicking the `(?)` icon in the question editor.